# Some obstacles in reversing a JNI Native library

Tags: android, radare2, c, java, shared-object

I deleted my last question (it was not still answered and none's effort was wasted) as I got back and thought to re-read JNI documentation, to find I misinterpreted some bits. Things are now clearer

Though I still cannot understand how JavaObject is passed on? Looking through radare2,

```
410: sym.Java_com_asobimo_common_jni_NativeResource_getZipedFile (int16_t arg1, int16_t arg3, int16_t arg4);
           ; var int16_t var_0h @ sp+0x0
           ; var int16_t var_ch @ sp+0xc
           ; var int16_t var_14h @ sp+0x14
           ; var int16_t var_18h @ sp+0x18
           ; var int16_t var_1ch @ sp+0x1c
           ; var int16_t var_34h @ sp+0x34
           ; var int16_t var_40h @ sp+0x40
           ; arg int16_t arg1 @ r0
           ; arg int16_t arg3 @ r2
           ; arg int16_t arg4 @ r3
           ; DATA XREF from aav.0x0000c664 @ +0x64
           0x0000c974  ~   f0b5           push {r4, r5, r6, r7, lr}
```

this is how the static function is called. I feel like the function makes references to passed class objects, since it subtracts `0x44` from `sp` letter on and then do some stuffs. But, how does this referencing works actually? I am pretty clueless. This is how the Java class looks like which corresponds to it:-

```
package com.asobimo.common.jni;

public final class NativeResource {
  static {
    System.loadLibrary("NativeResource");
  }

  public static native void deleteFile(String paramString);

  public static native byte[] getFile(String paramString);

  public static native byte[] getZipedFile(String paramString1, String paramString2);

  public static native boolean isZipedNormality(String paramString);

  public static native void saveFile(String paramString, byte[] paramArrayOfbyte, int paramInt);
}
```

Also, this is not really a necessary thing to answer (and it kinda shifts away from focus of it, I am sorry) but how radare identifies the arguments' size? As it's clear by `var int16_t var_40_h @ sp+0x40` being a reference (even though sp is subtracted by `0x40`) and the fact that string function were being called using `r0` pointer, over `r2` and `r3`, (which makes it more obvious that they probably are `int32_t`)

And why radare didn't assign `r1` to anything? And skipped `arg2`? It probably also has to do with `JavaObject`, but I can't really find anything by researching myself. I would really appreciate any help, I badly want that boss battle music hidden behind some encrypted zip files

In case it would help in making some sense, here is the `.so` file https://files.catbox.moe/foss7s.so

Comment: I highly recommend you to get in touch with [frida](https://github.com/frida/frida), especially with [jnitrace](https://github.com/chame1eon/jnitrace), which could help you to understand **how** and **where** shared object call jni functions which works with Java objects. Also will be good to read about [jni](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/index.html) to understand how does it work at all.

Comment: @OlvinRoght I will try Frida later, thanks! And I did read Oracle's documentation. It did cleared some doubts I had earlier (or I would say, I just read it previously in hurry) but now I don't get these stuffs

Comment: I have no much time to explain with details, but main idea is next: 1) native function receive pointer to Java *String* (I'll proceed with *getZipedFile* from post); 2) to get string bytes in native code used [GetStringChars](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#GetStringChars) which returns pointer to simple *char* array; 3) function do smth and then it uses [NewByteArray](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#New_PrimitiveType_Array_routines) to create Java array and return it. Maybe I'll post an answer later.

Comment: @OlvinRoght Yeap! but it also does some stuffs with some values in stack, which probably came from the Java program. but I have no idea what those values could be That's kinda necessary to figure out because it could be part of how the zip files are encrypted

Comment: `sub sp, #0x48` is allocation of `0x48` bytes for local variables. [Procedure Call Standard for the ARM architecture](https://developer.arm.com/docs/ihi0042/g/procedure-call-standard-for-the-arm-architecture-abi-2018q4-documentation).

Comment: @OlvinRoght But I don't understand this `str r0,[sp+var_40h]` There is nothing that have been done to stack before this instruction, so I assumed this have got to be something to do with it

Comment: `str r0,[sp+var_40h]` stores value of `r0` (which is first argument of called procedure and for jni functions it should be pointer to application context) into stack variable ([docs](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0552a/BABFGBDD.html)).

Comment: @OlvinRoght so `spr+var_40h` is supposed to mean, `var_40h`?

Comment: @OlvinRoght I think that is really the case, I opened up pseudo feature of radare and saw it assigned `r0` to `sp+0x40`. I need to learn more radare and arm architecture

Comment: I wonder, why is arg2 omitted then in the assembly? How does radare even comes up with these decisions? There must be some section in binary for it, I believe?

Comment: Probably `r1` isn't used in function, I can't say without research.

Comment: @OlvinRoght I had same thought, hm, Iet's see, I will just proceed to understand the assembly now with a ARM manual : P